# Converting optionMarker array into Marker array

Tags: android, marker

In an android application I want to check if a targetMarker is among the friendMarkers and if it is, then change that one friendMarker to the targetMarker, thus I don't have to remove the friendMarker and add the targetMarker. My question is how do I do this?

First, I need to convert the optionMarker array into a Marker array. 
Second, I need to check the Id-s
Third, I need to transform the friendMarker into a targetMarker

MainActivity - I activate the method in the actionbar: (the storeMarker is not fully functioning, tries to store the optionMarker array in a Marker array - unsuccessfully.

```
if (id == R.id.get_target) {
        // this is for getting the random target - and placing a marker on the Map
        targetClass = randomTarget.getRandomTarget();
        targetMarker = googleMap.addMarker(targetClass.marker);

            // here I get the friendMarkers
        MarkerOptions[] markers = randomTarget.getMarkers();
        Marker [] array;

            // the rest of the code is my try to convert the optionMarker array into                  Marker array
        for (int j = 0; j < markers.length; j++){
//              array[j] = storeMarkers().getId();
        }

        if (targetMarker.getId() == storeMarkers().getId()) {

        }
  }
```

And this is from the Target class - the optionMarker array

```
   // puts the online player's location into an array of markeroptions
      public MarkerOptions [] getMarkers() {

    playerFunctions = new PlayerFunctions();
    JSONArray array = playerFunctions.getAllOnline();

    try {
        MarkerOptions[] markers = new MarkerOptions[array.length()];
            for(int i = 0; i < array.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject element = array.getJSONObject(i);
                markers[i] = new MarkerOptions()
                        .position(new LatLng(Double.parseDouble((String)element.get("lat")), Double.parseDouble((String)element.get("long"))))
                        .title((String)element.get("name"));
             }
            return markers;
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return null;
        }
}
```

Thanks for the replies.